# Facing issue while implementing connection pooling with solr

Tags: solr, httpclient, solrj

I have this requirement where I want to limit the number of concurrent calls to solr say 50. So I am trying to implement connection pooling in HTTP client which is then used in solr object HttpSolrServer. Please find the code below

`
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

```
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
            HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST, 50);
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
            HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 50);


    HttpSolrServer httpSolrServer = new HttpSolrServer(
            "solr url",httpclient);

    SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery("*:*");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {

        long numFound = httpSolrServer.query(solrQuery).getResults()
                .getNumFound();
        System.out.println(numFound);
    }`
```

I was expecting only 50 connections to be created from my application to solr and then probably experience some slowness until the older connections are freed. However at every regular interval a new connection is created despite there are waiting connections at solr end and those connections are never used again.

Example Output

`tcp        0      0 192.168.0.241:22            192.168.0.109:54120         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.0.241:8190   ::ffff:192.168.0.109:47382  TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.0.241:8190   ::ffff:192.168.0.109:47383  ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.0.241:8190   ::ffff:192.168.0.109:47371  TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.0.241:8190   ::ffff:192.168.0.109:47381  TIME_WAIT`

where 109 is the ip where I am running my application and 241 is ip where solr is run. In this case  **ffff:192.168.0.109:47382**   will never be used again and it is finally terminated by solr

Am i going wrong somewhere.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Which version of SolrJ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

HttpSolrServer should be singleton. Create only one instance of HttpSolrServer per solr url.